# Replace part of window pathname

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've created a function that updates the window location whenever the user clicks on a new video (without reloading). The problem I'm having is that my function doesn't work properly because when I change the URL the first time it takes the url I just changed it to, and instead appends the ID.

For instance when the page first loads it fires off this function and makes the URL `example.com/123` which is correct, but whenever someone clicks on another video instead of replacing the 123 with the new ID it adds to it, making it `example.com/123678`.

```
function updatePath(uuid, title) {
    if (history.pushState) {
    var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + uuid;
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
    document.title = title + '- Video';
  }
}
```

How do I update this function so it's reusable, and replaces the correct part of the URL? Originally I was using query params and this worked well, but I believe `window.location.pathname` is updating every time it's ran, so it's not replacing properly.

Comment: Just get the directory part of the pathname and append the new ID. You're appending the new ID to the whole pathname.

Comment: Why don't you use `hash`? `mysupervidz.com#123` Or query strings like `?v=123`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan He mentioned that he was using a query param originally.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592139/how-to-dynamically-get-the-directory-of-the-file-running

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It's not suitable for this application. I've had to change from using them because it was causing issues.